# Creating .webp stores in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, geotiff-tiff

Using GeoServer, is there a way to convert my existing GeoTIFF raster data sources into a WebP format?

My goal is to render these WebP formatted layers on a OpenLayers map. The GeoTIFF layers render as expected, but I would like to boost my performance slightly using the WebP format if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for WebP, neither as a data source, nor as an output format. Both ends have pluggable extension points, so it's possible to create a GeoServer extension adding support for them, with some Java programming.